# set three header div's 25% 50% 25% Horizontally

Tags: html, css

I want to set three header div's 25% 50% 25%  Horizontally, shown in [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8RjBC.png), have laid them three div's in header div with corresponding css, but the div's are placed vertically shown [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ramas/khbv2mac/).

Have checked with previous answers which I couldn't get a lead, give me a directions please! Thanks

HTML code:

```
    <div id="header">
    <div id="header-left" class="div-border">
    <h6 align="center">Image holder</h6>
    </div>
    <div id="header-middle" class="div-border">
    <h1 align="center">Dashboard</h1>
    </div> 
    <div id="header-right" class="div-border">
    <h6>
    <span >
    <span style="line-height: 24px;" id="border-around">
    <b>Profile    |    Help    |   Admin </b>
    </span>
    </span>
    </h6>
    </div>
    </div>
```

CSS code:

```
    #header {
        background-color:#fecb00;
        color:white;
       text-align:center;
      padding:5px;
     }
     #header-left {
        width: 25%;
     }
     #header-middle {
        width: 50%;
     }
     #header-right {
        width: 25%;
     }
    .div-border {
       border: 2px solid silver;
     }
     #border-around {
        border: 1px solid #000;
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set `box-sizing: border-box` to include borders to width calculation, set `display: inline-box` to display elements inline, `vertical-align: middle` and eliminate white spacing between divs.

```
.div-border {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/khbv2mac/1/

Answer (score 1):

- Your elements are displayed as `block` elements by default, which means that they will take an entire 'line' to themselves unless floated. You can either float your elements, or display them `inline-block`.
- The accumulated width of your three elements is wider than 100% of the width of the page, because their borders are not included in the width you specify. You can fix this by changing `box-sizing`.

Note: I have commented out the white-space between your `inline-block` elements. Because they are displayed inline, space between them will be acknowledged.

```css
body{margin:0}
#header {
    background-color:#fecb00;
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
}
#header-left {
    width: 25%;
}
#header-middle {
    width: 50%;
}
#header-right {
    width: 25%;
}
.div-border {
    /* Style changes here */
    display:inline-block;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    border: 2px solid silver;
}
#border-around {
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
    <div id="header-left" class="div-border">
        <h6 align="center">Image holder</h6>
    </div><!--
 --><div id="header-middle" class="div-border">
        <h1 align="center">Dashboard</h1>
    </div><!--
 --><div id="header-right" class="div-border">
        <h6><span><span style="line-height: 24px;" id="border-around"><b>Profile    |    Help    |   Admin </b></span></span></h6>
    </div>
</div>
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/8n4486ca/)

Answer (score 1):

**used to floating element as like this**

```
*{   // add this line 
    box-sizing:border-box;   // add this line 
}   // add this line 
#header {
    background-color:#fecb00;
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
    padding:5px;
    overflow:hidden;   // add this line 
}
#header-left {
    width: 25%;
    float:left;   // add this line 
}
#header-middle {
    width: 50%;
    float:left;   // add this line 
}
#header-right {
    width: 25%;
    float:left;   // add this line 
}
.div-border {
    border: 2px solid silver;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/khbv2mac/3/)**

Answer (score 1):

you can try it using css order property .

code:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
 #header {
        background-color:#fecb00;
        color:white;
       text-align:center;
      padding:5px;
      width:100%;
      display: -webkit-flex; /* Safari */
    display: flex;
     }
     #header-left {
        width: 25%;
        -webkit-order:1;
        order:1;
     }
     #header-middle {
        width: 49%;
        -webkit-order:2;
        order:2;
     }
     #header-right {
        width: 25%;
        -webkit-order:3;
        order:3;
     }
    .div-border {
       border: 2px solid silver;
     }
     #border-around {
        border: 1px solid #000;
     }
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="header">
    <div id="header-left" class="div-border">
    <h6 align="center">Image holder</h6>
    </div>
    <div id="header-middle" class="div-border">
    <h1 align="center">Dashboard</h1>
    </div> 
    <div id="header-right" class="div-border">
    <h6>
    <span >
    <span style="line-height: 24px;" id="border-around">
    <b>Profile    |    Help    |   Admin </b>
    </span>
    </span>
    </h6>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/invincibleJai/sbuveeLw/

Comment: Any particular reason for this 'width: 49%;'? Thanks @jai

Comment: nothing much just kept some % for margin, padding , border ... i usually do , but not needed.

Comment: I just follow your margin idea, Thanks @jai, a small request, How do I make the border div big please! like this http://i.imgur.com/CSMO8zf.png, Thank you so much!!!